# Reading Strings from a file to an ArrayList then converting to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

The goal is to read each word from a large file (multiple words and numbers on multiple lines) to a 2d Array. To do this, I am trying to read each word from the file to an ArrayList, than converting the ArrayList to a 2d Array. However, the output I'm getting for each element of the 2d Array is the file name.

Portion of the file:

> 1  1   Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton   female
>   1  1   Allison, Master. Hudson Trevor  male
>   1  0   Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine    female
>   1  0   Allison, Mr. Hudson Joshua Creighton    male    30
>   1  0   Allison, Mrs. Hudson J C (Bessie Waldo Daniels) female  25

My code:

```
public class Titanic {

private final static String fileName = "/Users/Andrew/Desktop/titanic.txt";


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s1 = new Scanner (fileName);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (s1.hasNext()) {
        list.add(s1.next());
    }
    s1.close();


    String[][] data = new String [list.size()][9];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
           data[i][j] = list.get(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(data[0][0]);

   }
}
```

Comment: The format you're reading these in is a bit confusing.  You're not guaranteed 9 tokens across all entries; in your last case, you've got 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a `File` to your `Scanner`. You could use "user.home" to get the home folder. I would read to a `List<String[]>` (and use the [diamond operator `<>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)), you could use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) and [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Something like

```
private final static String fileName = "Desktop/titanic.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
            fileName))) {
        while (s1.hasNextLine()) {
            list.add(s1.nextLine().split("\\s+"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int pos = 0;
    String[][] data = new String[list.size()][];
    for (String[] arr : list) {
        data[pos++] = arr;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you. I see why I was getting that output now.

Answer (score 0):

*change* 
**Scanner s1 = new Scanner (fileName);** in this case you are passing an string to the function, a file need to be passed.
**to 
Scanner s1 = new Scanner (new  File(fileName))**